# Avoid building /refs/heads/master in TeamCity build job for Github pull requests

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a job set up that builds the merge commit from each Github pull request, using the approach outlined [on the JetBrains blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/), i.e. with a VCS root with the branch specification `+:refs/heads/pull/(*/merge)`. This works fine - every time a pull request is submitted or updated with new commits, the build job is triggered.

However, it is also triggered for changes to `master`, for example when a pull request is merged. I have another job that builds and tests changes to master (that also publishes successful builds to our staging environment) so I don't want to run this job for those changes.

How do I *exclude* `master` changes in the VCS root?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give it in two places.

You can either add a `-:master` in the build trigger (there is a textbox) at the end of the input regular expressions or you can add a `-:master` in the *Branch specifications* in the VCS root spec (but be sure to not have `master` in the *Default branch*)

Comment: Ah - apparently, I hadn't realized what role the `+` sign had in my branch specification. I've added this to the branch spec of these build projects, and will mark this as accepted as soon as I can confirm that it works. Thanks a lot!